# Multiple CollectionViews inside a Scrollview

Tags: iphone, ios, scrollview, horizontal-scrolling, collectionview

I am trying to create a horizontal scroller which starts with a collectionview (group1), when scrolling reaches the end of group1, I need another collectionview to page into view, and so on.

I am new to this and I can't quite figure out how to solve it.
I have no problem creating a scrollview which adds three different views, however since the contentsize is set like so: `self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(320*[controllers count], 460);`

A specific view only displays as many cells as it can fit, leaving the rest behind the next view as you scroll.So to clarify this, I need to scroll inside one collectionview before the scrollview pops me over to another collectionview.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just make one collection view with three sections?

Comment: the initial view will only hold a "create new group" view (not scrollable), each time you add a new group i'd like them to be accessible by scrolling to the right, no matter how many groups are added. @0x7fffffff

Comment: Sorry, I don't know where I got the three from, but I still stand by what I said. If you use one collection with multiple sections the implementation would be far easier. Instead of creating a new collection and adjusting the scroll view, all you would have to do is manipulate your datasource and call `reloadData`. Additionally, use on one collection would be much better on memory.